# Seeking Family Tree Software with Photo Integration that tags faces of people?

Tags: software-recommendations, photo, organization

I have done a bit of research on various family tree makers but some can be pricey and I would hate to spend the money on something to find out it does not work how I want.

Is there a family tree software that lets you connect photographs to folks and maybe allows you to 'tag' the faces of people in the photos?

I have a lot of family photos and would like a better solution than "2nd person in the third row".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Family Historian will handle same sex relationships without problems. It also has a variation on what you want with photos.

If you upload a photo with multiple people in it you can draw a box around one person and just link that box to an individual in your tree and just that box is shown when you do a report on that person but you can also include the full photo in your report. The image below shows this in action.

[image]

Family Historian is available with a free 30 day trial so you can try it out from [Calico Pie](https://www.family-historian.co.uk/)

Comment: Are you familiar with how it handles photo organization? Is it easy to find a picture you're looking for?

Comment: It depends on exactly what you mean. If you have given the image a unique name or specific name it is easy to find as there is a media tab that shows a list of all the images. You can then search the list. Double clicking on an image in the list opens a popup window with a thumbnail of the image in it. As I said try the demo version and play around with the sample project that is where the image above came from.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement that you have looks like it can be met using FamilySearch.org and its [FamilySearch Update for Tagging Photos and Editing Portraits](https://www.familysearch.org/blog/en/familysearch-update-tagging-photos/):

> To tag a person in a photo, access the photo from the “Memories” tab
>   on their person page and click on the photo of interest. As you hover
>   over the photo, other tags might appear. Click on an untagged person
>   and begin typing to create a new tag. You will probably notice that
>   instead of a circular tagging tool, a square box now appears, making
>   tagging people near the edge of photos easier. Square tags also make
>   it easier to tag things besides faces like documents or photos of
>   tombstones.

Comment: Thank you - this does look like what I want.  Unfortunately, FamilySearch does not allow for same-sex couples - and as I am in one, this would hinder my tree-building quite a bit.

Comment: I can understand why that would be a showstopper.

Comment: FamilySearch is planning to add same sex couples. See: https://www.deseretnews.com/article/900021544/lds-churchs-familysearch-database-to-add-same-sex-families-to-family-tree-feature.html

Answer (score 1):

The [Gramps genealogy program](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Download) can handle same sex relationships without issue.

You can use the "[Photo Tagging Gramplet](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Photo_Tagging_Gramplet)" third party addon to tag peoples faces.

Gramps is a free program.

[image: example of photo tagging in gramps]

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a family photo with [Family Circles](https://fc.jenika.com) a project of mine.

It is better if you interact with it [1939 Orsi Family](https://fc.jenika.com/examples/1939Orsi.html).

[image]

Comment: If you are affiliated with the website named, you should disclose that - from the G&FH SE "Expected Behavior":

Comment: Avoid overt self-promotion.

The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.